# Trouble installing ezdxf package - fonttools error

Tags: python, installation, ezdxf, ttx-fonttools

I am attempting to install ezdxf for python and have been running into the following error whenever attempting to import it into a program (see attached image)

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this / steps to help me figure it out?

[image]

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing a few times, and I haven't been able to locate ony documentation online about errors of this type

Comment: This issue can only be solved by installing the `ezdxf` v1.1.3b0 beta version.

Comment: More information about this issue can be found in the forum of  `ezdxf` at [github](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/discussions/958).